# An exact solution for linear differential equation with non-constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following equation:
$$ay''+b y'+xy = 0$$
Assume that $y(0)=A$, $y'(0) = B$, where $a,b,A,B\in \mathbb{R}$

> Solve for $y$.

I am interested in this question because if we take $a=0$, the problem becomes easy to solve, but here we deal with more complicated equation.

Here are my two ideas how to solve this problem:

1. We may assume that solutions are smooth, therefore we may rewrite
   this equation using substitution $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$. However i don't know whether that would give me all the solutions.
2. I was trying to associate characteristic polynomial to this equation, but it gave me no result.

This question is a first step to solve more general equation:
$$c x y +\sum_{n=0}^{m}c_n y^{(n)}=0$$

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Consider $y(x)=\mu(x) f(x)$, with $\mu$ presently unknown. Write the DE for $f$. The coefficient of $f'$ is $2a \mu'+b\mu$; choose $\mu$ such that this coefficient vanishes. In the resulting equation let $t=x+c$. With appropriate choice of $c$ you recover the Airy equation.